# Бесплатный "аналог" ISPManager

Tags: сервер, администрирование, vds

Дело такое - нуждаюсь в лёгенькой панели для управления сервером (VDS), с маленьким функционалом - файл.менеджер, просмотр error \ access логов, заведение и управление БД.

Пробовал поставить VESTA CP - ужаснулся, снёс.

Кто что может посоветовать? И демки бы посмотреть заодно. Полапать, так сказать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webmin, ISPConfig. Демки есть у обоих.